# How do we change the cursor starting position of a text field component of Material UI (Version 5.14.6)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, angular-material, material-design, materialize

How do we change the cursor starting position of a text field component of Material UI? We are using the latest version of material UI and we are using Test Field component in my project but the cursor stating position is not at right place. So, how we change the starting position of the cursor.

We try these 3 methods

First

```
<TextField
  // ... other props
  sx={{
    "& input": {
      padding: "10px",
    },
  }}
/>
```

Second

```
<TextField
  label="Username"
  placeholder="Enter your username"
  inputProps={{ selectionStart: 5 }} // Set the starting cursor position
/>
```

Third, we use useRef to acheive this but this is also not working

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function CustomizedTextField() {
  const [startCursorPosition, setStartCursorPosition] = useState(5);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
      inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(startCursorPosition, startCursorPosition);
    }
  }, [startCursorPosition]);

  return (
    <TextField
      label="Username"
      placeholder="Enter your username"
      inputRef={inputRef}
      onFocus={() => setStartCursorPosition(5)} // Set the desired starting position
    />
  );
}
```

Image  [Material UI Text Field image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvqXJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the html input field style properties of the TextField component by using the `inputProps` property.

```js
<TextField 
  size="small"
  inputProps={{
    style: {
      paddingLeft: "50px"
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: In Material UI Text Field component, by default one line is show below the text area, can we hide that line. If possible to hide then suggest me how we do this?

Comment: Do  you mean the padding below the input field?  If so, you can add the `size="small"` property to the component.  I'll change the answer to reflect that.

Comment: No, I want to hide the text area line that is coming in the text field. I attached the image in the questions, can you see?